# Output always produces 0

Tags: c++

for some reason my code seems to produce zeroes for one of my lines of output, not exactly sure what the problem is but I think it may have to do with the difference between int and double values, and when they are converted.

Towards the bottom of this switch case, the values for the "Normalized representation" - reN2, grN2, blN2 will produces 0 regardless of what the initial input is. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.

Let me know if there is any confusion on the variable names. This is a homework assignment that won't be graded by a person so I didn't think to make the variables more different because only I would see them.

```
case'd':
    double red2, green2, blue2; 
    cout << "Input r, g, b: ";
    cin >> red2 >> green2 >> blue2;

    int reI, grI, blI;
    reI = red2*255;
    grI = green2*255;
    blI = blue2*255;

    cout << "Integer representation: " << reI << ", " << grI << ", "
    << blI;
    cout << endl;

    if(reI > grI && reI > blI && green2 != blue2)
        cout << "Reddish pixel";
    else if(grI > reI && grI > blI && red2 != blue2)
        cout << "Greenish pixel";
    else if(blI > reI && blI > grI && green2 != red2)
        cout << "Blueish pixel";
    else if(blue2 == 0.0 && red2 == 0.0 && green2 == 0.0)
        cout << "Black pixel";

    cout << endl;
    if((reI+grI+blI) != 0)
    {
        double reN2, grN2, blN2;
        reN2 = reI/(reI+grI+blI);
        grN2 = grI/(reI+grI+blI);
        blN2 = blI/(reI+grI+blI);

        cout << "Normalized representation: " << reN2 << ", " << grN2 
        << ", " << blN2;
    }

    break;
```

Comment: All three values are 0? And have you tried debugging it?

Answer (score 2):

`reI, grI, blI` are integers. When you perform operations with them, they are treated as integers and C++ does *not* automagically decide that you want float division instead of integer division.

A lazy way to force automatic conversion would be to add a `* 1.0` in the numerator: `reN2 = reI * 1.0 / (reI + grI + blI);`.

Or use an explicit cast from `int` to `double`.

Comment: Also, you're using implicit conversion from double to int at the top of your code, which probably produces a warning in the compiler. Make the conversion explicit. Also, this way you'd always be rounding down, so even 200.9 becomes 200.

Answer (score 2):

An integer divided by itself plus some other integers (i.e. `i / (i + n)` Is always going to be 0 (assuming n is positive)

You need to do some casting so it is not integer division and you get a double result.

`reN2 = (double)reI/(reI+grI+blI);`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in these 3 lines:

```
    reN2 = reI/(reI+grI+blI);
    grN2 = grI/(reI+grI+blI);
    blN2 = blI/(reI+grI+blI);
```

The variables `reN2`, `grI`, and `blI` are of type int. As a result, while the result of these 3 operations is stored as a float value, there was no further processing of these floats with another float value (i.e multiplying them by a floating value like 2.5, etc...). As a result, the final output in your case has no decimal points. Now, I'll explain why the output is always zero. (I'm assuming that these 3 values cannot be negative, as they are fixed between 0 and 255).

Let's say that you have 25 in reI, 23 in blI, and 12 in grI. Now, in any of your operations, you have one of the values; let's take red as an example, over the sum of all three variables which includes the one in the numerator. So pertaining to the example, we have:

```
    25 / (25 + 23 + 12)
```

Most of the situations resemble this; the numerator being less than the denominator. As such, your result is always less than 1 and greater than 0, giving it a value like 0.xx. Now, since your operations are only on integers, there are no decimal values attached to that, which results to 0.xx being rounded up to 0. That's why you always get a 0 as a result.

The simplest way to fix this would be by using explicit casting. Changing these lines to:

```
    reN2 = (double)reI/(reI+grI+blI);
    grN2 = (double)grI/(reI+grI+blI);
    blN2 = (double)blI/(reI+grI+blI);
```

Should sort the problem. Here we cast the variable to double. This simply means thatwe tell the compiler to convert the value stored in `reI` or `grI` or `blI` to a double from a float.

Alternatively, you could multiply the resulting expressions by `1.0`. This time, an operation (a multiplication one) takes place with a floating point value, which leads to the resulting expression to be saved as a floating point value. I'll give credit here to @Lagerbaer for his idea here.

A third way would be to change your data type for `reI`, `grI` and `blI` to `double` when you initialize them. I'm not sure whether you are allowed to do that or not in your assignment, so I'm just mentioning it here.